# Transición de color ente paginas en ViewPager de Android

Tags: java, android, android-layout

Estoy creando una `onbarding-screen` tengo ya las paginas que se conforman en un fragmento con una imagen y texto añadidos en un `ViewPager`, solo me falta eso cambiar la transición entre las páginas que dependiendo del color de fondo de cada página haga un fundido de color entre ellas.

```
pagina1 => roja
pagina2 => verde
pagina3 => azul
```

transición de color rojo a verde a azul

Answer (score 2):

Esto podría ser la solución que buscas [**ArgbEvaluator**](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/animation/ArgbEvaluator.html)

Un ejemplo básico de implementación en el método ***onPageScrolled()***  del *ViewPager*:

```
int mStartColor = Color.RED;
int mEndColor = Color.GREEN;
ArgbEvaluator mArgbEvaluator;

@Override
public void onPageScrolled(final int position, float positionOffset, 
                                 int positionOffsetPixels) {
    //Instanciaamos el objeto ArgbEvaluator
    if (mArgbEvaluator == null)
        mArgbEvaluator = new ArgbEvaluator();
    //Obtenemos el color progresivamente
    int color = (Integer) mArgbEvaluator.evaluate(positionOffset, mStartColor, mEndColor);
    //Cambiamos el color de fondo de la vista
    mBackgroundView.setBackgroundColor(color);
}
```

Ahora un ejemplo de como implementarlo de forma mas extendida acontinuación:

Teniendo en cuenta que tienes una actividad que extenderá de ***AppCompatActivity***, un adaptador que extenderá de ***FragmentStatePagerAdapter*** y un fragmento que extenderá de ***Fragment***.

*MyActivity.java*:

```
public class MyActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener {

private static final String TAG = MyActivity.class.getSimpleName();

private ViewPager mViewPager;
private MyPagerAdapter mAdapter;
private RelativeLayout mBackgroundView;

int[] colorListBackground;
ArgbEvaluator mArgbEvaluator;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_my);

    colorListBackground = new int[]{
            ContextCompat.getColor(this, R.color.color_red),
            ContextCompat.getColor(this, R.color.color_green),
            ContextCompat.getColor(this, R.color.color_blue)};

    mBackgroundView = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.root_background);
    mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);

    mAdapter = new MyPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

    setupViewPager(mViewPager);
    mViewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(1);
    mViewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(this);
    //mViewPager.setPageTransformer(true, new CardPagerTransformer());

    mArgbEvaluator = new ArgbEvaluator();
}

/**
 * Poblamos el adaptador y lo asociamos al viewPager.
 * 
 * @param viewPager     viewPager donde se asociará el
 *                      adaptador con los fragmentos 
 *                      creados.
 */
private void setupViewPager(ViewPager viewPager) {
    mAdapter.addFragment(new MyFragment.Builder()
            .setBackgroundColor(colorListBackground[0])
            .setImageResource(R.drawable.image_page_0)
            .setTitle(getResources().getString(R.string.title_page_0))
            .setDescription(getResources().getString(R.string.description_page_0))
            .build());
    mAdapter.addFragment(new MyFragment.Builder()
            .setBackgroundColor(colorListBackground[1])
            .setImageResource(R.drawable.image_page_1)
            .setTitle(getResources().getString(R.string.title_page_1))
            .setDescription(getResources().getString(R.string.description_page_1))
            .build());
    mAdapter.addFragment(new MyFragment.Builder()
            .setBackgroundColor(colorListBackground[2])
            .setImageResource(R.drawable.image_page_2)
            .setTitle(getResources().getString(R.string.title_page_2))
            .setDescription(getResources().getString(R.string.description_page_2))
            .build());
    viewPager.setAdapter(mAdapter);
}

@Override
public void onPageScrolled(final int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {
    //Actualizamos el color del background
    int colorUpdate = (Integer) mArgbEvaluator.evaluate(
            positionOffset, colorListBackground[position],
            colorListBackground[position == colorListBackground.length-1 ? position : position + 1]);
    mBackgroundView.setBackgroundColor(colorUpdate);

    //Actualizamos el color del StatusBar
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
        getWindow().setStatusBarColor(colorUpdate);
    }
}

@Override
public void onPageSelected(int position) {
    //Otras acciones a realizar si es necesario
}

@Override
public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {
    //Otras acciones a realizar si es necesario
}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    if (!(mViewPager.getCurrentItem() == 0)) {
        mViewPager.setCurrentItem(mViewPager.getCurrentItem() - 1);
    } else {
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
}

}
```

*MyPagerAdapter.java*:

```
public class MyPagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {

private final List<Fragment> mFragmentList = new ArrayList<>();

public MyPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
    super(fm);
}

@Override
public Fragment getItem(int position) {
    return mFragmentList.get(position);
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return mFragmentList.size();
}

public void addFragment(Fragment fragment) {
    mFragmentList.add(fragment);
}

}
```

*MyFragment.java*:

```
public class MyFragment extends Fragment {

private static final String TAG = MyFragment.class.getSimpleName();

public static final String EXTRA_PAGER_BACKGROUND = "com.myPackage.android.PAGER_BACKGROUND";
public static final String EXTRA_PAGER_IMAGE = "com.myPackage.android.PAGER_IMAGE";
public static final String EXTRA_PAGER_TITLE = "com.myPackage.android.PAGER_TITLE";
public static final String EXTRA_PAGER_DESCRIPTION = "com.myPackage.android.PAGER_DESCRIPTION";

public static final int NO_IMAGE = -1;

public static class Builder {

    private int mBackgroundColor;
    private int mImageResource;
    private String mTitle;
    private String mDescription;

    public Builder() {
        mImageResource = NO_IMAGE;
    }

    public Builder setBackgroundColor(int color) {
        mBackgroundColor = color;
        return this;
    }

    public Builder setImageResource(int image) {
        mImageResource = image;
        return this;
    }

    public Builder setTitle(String title) {
        mTitle = title;
        return this;
    }

    public Builder setDescription(String description) {
        mDescription = description;
        return this;
    }

    public MyFragment build() {
        return MyFragment.newInstance(mBackgroundColor, mImageResource, mTitle, mDescription);
    }
}

private int background_color;
private int imagen_drawable;
private String title, description;

ImageView mImageView;
TextView mTitleView;
TextView mDescriptionview;

public static MyFragment newInstance(int background_color, int imagen_drawable, String title, String description) {
    MyFragment fragment = new MyFragment();
    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    bundle.putInt(EXTRA_PAGER_BACKGROUND, background_color);
    bundle.putInt(EXTRA_PAGER_IMAGE, imagen_drawable);
    bundle.putString(EXTRA_PAGER_TITLE, title);
    bundle.putString(EXTRA_PAGER_DESCRIPTION, description);
    fragment.setArguments(bundle);
    //fragment.setRetainInstance(true);
    return fragment;
}

@SuppressLint("MissingSuperCall")
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    background_color = getArguments().getInt(EXTRA_PAGER_BACKGROUND);
    imagen_drawable = getArguments().getInt(EXTRA_PAGER_IMAGE);
    title = getArguments().getString(EXTRA_PAGER_TITLE);
    description = getArguments().getString(EXTRA_PAGER_DESCRIPTION);
}

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    ViewGroup rootView = (ViewGroup) inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_my, container, false);

    mImageView = (ImageView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.img_pager_image);
    mTitleView = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.txt_pager_title);
    mDescriptionView = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.txt_page_description);

    mTitleView.setText(this.title);
    mDescriptionView.setText(this.description);

    if (imagen_drawable != NO_IMAGE)
        mImageView.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(this.imagen_drawable));

    return rootView;
}

@Override
public void onDestroyView() {
    super.onDestroyView();
}

@Override
public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
}

@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
}

}
```